# How can I convert the rows of a C# Datatable object into a series of select statements?

Tags: c#, datatable

I was working on debugging a separate issue and found that, for the purposes of solving that problem, it would have been helpful to create an extension method that takes a c# datatable object and converts the contents of each of its rows into a series of SELECT statements, grabbing the data from each cell and the column name of each column, and then placing a UNION ALL between each as a way of rebuilding the table and all its contents.

In effect, we would produce something like the following that you can dump into ssms to easily view the contents :

```
SELECT "1-1-2020" as [CreateDate], 18 as [NumOfGuests] 
UNION ALL
SELECT "1-2-2020" as [CreateDate], 48 as [NumOfGuests]
```

I've banged my head on this one a while and haven't come up with a good solution so far, any and all input or direction would be appreciated.

UPDATE :

To answer Olivier's question regarding what, specifically, is the problem; I've been thinking of looping over the content of the table as follows (haven't had a chance to test this yet) but feel like there's got to be a better solution than the one I've come up with.

```cs
public static string ParseDataColumns(this DataTable dataTable)
{
    var sb = "";

    if (dataTable.Columns.Count <= 0) return sb;
    sb += "SELECT ";
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Ordinal != 0)
            {
                sb += ", " + row[column].ToString() + " AS [" + column.ColumnName + "]";    
            }
            else
            {
                sb += row[column].ToString() + " AS [" + column.ColumnName + "]";
            }
        }
    sb += "UNION ALL" + dataTable.TableName;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The title is about comma delimited strings. The text about unioned SELECT statements. What do you need? What have you tried? DataTables have rows and columns collections. Can't you just loop over them and create the reuqired string? Where is the problem?

Comment: Apologies, as I wrote out the question I realized that it'd be more useful as just a bunch of unioned select statements and never updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ with a helper method to do this. The helper transforms a C# datatype into a SQL Literal, you may need to add other cases:

```
public static class DataRowExt {
    public static string SQLLiteral(this DataRow r, DataColumn c) {
        if (c.DataType == typeof(String))
            return $"\"{r.Field<string>(c.ColumnName)}\"";
        else if (c.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            return $"\"{r.Field<DateTime>(c.ColumnName).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}\"";
        else
            return r[c.ColumnName].ToString();
    }

    public static string SQLLiteral(this DataTable dt) =>
        String.Join("\nUNION ALL\n", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => "SELECT " + String.Join(", ", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => $"{r.SQLLiteral(c)} AS [{c.ColumnName}]"))));
}
```

Now your answer is simply:

```
public static string ParseDataColumns(this DataTable dataTable) => dataTable.SQLLiteral();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq to get all data from the c# table, then serialize it into the json file. Parse the json string as the list of string-string tuples. Finally, covert each tuple to string, adding "select"s and other sql keywords. This will work for simple data formats.

Alternatively, you can just export the table in CSV format and import it to ssms.

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating extra files if at all possible, and simply go from datatable to the select string within a single extension method.